# Script stops printing output when input changes

Tags: python

I'm making a coin flip game that asks the user "Heads or Tails", and after the user chooses one of the two, it will respond back saying either "correct" or "wrong". When I run my code, it works perfectly fine if I keep repeating either heads or tails. But if I switch it up like something like heads, heads, tails . It won't ask me the question "Heads or Tails" anymore. And what's weird is sometimes after switching it up it will ask but then eventually it stops. This is my code:

```
import random
coin=["CORRECT!", "WRONG!"]

hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")

while hot == "heads":
    if hot=="heads":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
            hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")

while hot =="tails":
    if hot=="tails":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
            hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")
```

And then this right here is the problem I'm talking about when I run it

```
Heads or Tails? 
heads
CORRECT!
Heads or Tails? 
tails
CORRECT!
Heads or Tails? 
tails
WRONG!
Heads or Tails? 
heads
```

After that last heads I put it doesn't say correct or wrong, and sometimes it doesn't show it even earlier when I run it.

Comment: You add code to your question. But format it properly so it would be easier to read.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code, otherwise we can't help you!

Comment: You're probably using the `random` module for emulating the coin flips; but you need to show us your code before we can help you.

Comment: Thanks guys I just edited it, I'm not sure if it sends you a notification that I did , so I'm leaving this comment just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the same using:

```
hot = raw_input('Heads or Tails?\n')

while hot != 'quit':

    if hot == random.choice(['heads', 'tails']):
        print 'Correct!'
        hot = raw_input('Heads or Tails?\n')
    else:
        print 'Wrong!'
        hot = raw_input('Heads or Tails?\n')
```

This allows the user to continue flipping the coin until the user enters 'quit'.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't strange that your program stops after you stop responding "tails". This is because of basic control flow. You've used five types of control flow in your program.

First, unless told otherwise, control will flow from one statement to the next. So `import random` happens first, then the assignment of `coin`, and so on.

Second, you've used function calls such as `raw_input()` and `random.choice()`. These run other subprograms, which we don't need to consider very deeply here since all of them `return` to your main program.

Third came two [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) loop constructs. These contain some section of code they repeat as long as their condition is satisfied; crucially, they therefore *end* when it is not. So the first loop actually ends when you respond something other than "heads".

Fourth, you have an [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) within each loop. This runs its contents if a condition is satisfied, just like `while`, but doesn't repeat. Since the condition you used is exactly the same as the surrounding `while`, these checks are redundant; we wouldn't be executing this part of the program if the condition wasn't met.

Fifth you used a `for` statement; these make loops, like `while`, but process every entry of some iterable. In this case, that served no purpose because there is only one entry in `range(1)` and you never actually used it. Like the `if`, it is redundant.

Having deciphered these, we see the control flow moves from "heads" loop to "tails" loop then simply ends, having run out of program. To keep the program running we must have a loop that does *not* end, for instance:

```
while True:
    if hot=="heads":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
            hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")

    if hot=="tails":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
            hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")
```

This loop exhibits another issue, namely that nothing checks that the answer entered was either heads or tails. It will therefore get stuck running *nothing* if we give another answer. You can solve this by ensuring we ask for a guess in *every* iteration, and for some extra flair, even respond to invalid guesses using `else`:

```
while True:
    hot=raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")
    if hot=="heads":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
    elif hot=="tails":
        for i in range(1):
            print random.choice(coin)
    else:
        print "I don't know what side of a coin that is."
```

Note that I moved the `raw_input` call outside of the conditional sections. Since it was equal for all branches, it doesn't need duplication. I also used `elif` and `else` to tie together the conditional sections, ensuring only one of them will run for any iteration (each time through the loop). And about duplication, your two conditionals perform the exact same operation! You've taken a shortcut and not actually calculated which side the coin landed on - only used its odds of success. Let's fix that too.

```
sides = ("heads", "tails")

while True:
    hot = raw_input("Heads or Tails? \n")
    if hot in sides:
        toss = random.choice(sides)
        if hot == toss:
            print "Correct"
        else:
            print "Incorrect"
    else:
        print "I don't know what side of a coin that is."
```

Note that there are two `if` statements on different levels this time, each with their own `else`. These are independent, aside from the fact that the inner one only runs if the outer condition was true. All sorts of control flow statements (ending in `:`) can be nested this way.